# How to prevent apt upgrade from installing manually installed library

Tags: apt-get, apt, pinning

I have a library that I built from sources in a version that is not yet available in the debian archives. Another package requires it and `apt upgrade` wants to install the older version. How can I prevent this?

Details: I have a problem with Sane that has been fixed in its latest release (libsane: 1.0.27). In Debian the most current available version is 1.0.26.

I tried pinning it like this:

```
Package: libsane
Pin: version 1.0.27
Pin-Priority: 900
```

but that didn't change the attempt to install libsane when I run apt upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `apt-get upgrade` to prevent apt from installing new packages.

`apt upgrade` behaves like the behavior you described.

From the man pages:

[man apt-get](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) Section `upgrade`

> upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed [...] under no circumstances are [...] packages not already installed retrieved and installed.

[man apt](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt.8.en.html) Section `upgrade`

> upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed [...]. New packages will be installed, but existing packages will never be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily hold specific packages:

```
apt-mark hold libsane
```

Comment: that worked. Could you elaborate what it does and when "temporarily" ends?

Answer (score 0):

Two easiest options are:

- use `equivs` package to create a dummy package. Extended tutorial [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726317).
- alter the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file erasing unwanted dependency there. Just find the package about which dependencies `apt` nags and delete relevant items from dependencies line. For example, edit line `Depends: libco (>= 2.14), libefivar (>= 30), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)` to `Depends: libefivar (>= 30)` if you want to throw out `libco` and `libssl1.0.0` requirement.

The second option requires you to have this package installed. However, you can easily install package with `apt-get download packagename` and `dpkg --ignore-deps=` commands.

Comment: wouldn't the second option be moot after the next apt update?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs no, it won't. But installing this package again may change its entry in status file.

Comment: The second option does not work for me. I removed `libsane` from the dependencies of `xsane` but `apt upgrade` wants to update `xsane` and install `libsane`.

Comment: As I have said, installing this package again may change its entry in status file. Install new version of `xsane` with `apt-get download` and `dpkg --ignore-deps...` and then remove its dependencies from `status` file. `apt upgrade` will work fine.